# React variable style name

Tags: reactjs

In react I am using scss for styling and when I set the style of an element it is always set like this: `<div className={styles.container}> </div>`. which is connected to a stylesheet that I have linked to the style variable. Is there a way I can set the style name dynamically without using any other libararies?

For example, var i = 'error'. And then set the style to something like this `<div className={styles.[i]}> </div>`. Which would use the class .error in the scss file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the dot and it should work fine

```
<div className={styles[i]}> </div>
```